# Is there a phrase 'There is why'?

Tags: grammar

Can I omit ‘a reason’ in the following sentence? If not, why can’t I omit it?

> There is a reason why so many of us are attracted to recorded music these days, especially given personal music players are common and people are listening to music through headphones a lot.

Comment: You can't omit "a reason." You could change "why" to "that", though.

Comment: You can't omit *a reason* because "There is" needs a noun phrase after it.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot omit "a reason" for a couple reasons.

One is that after "There is..." you need to have a noun or noun phrase. "...why..." cannot form a noun phrase. "... a reason why... " is a noun phrase.

Also, in the general structure "... a/the reason [why + clause]", the portion in brackets is a *relative clause* modifying "reason", so if you remove "reason", you leave a relative clause with nothing to modify.